# Can't open label file. (This can be normal only if you use MSCOCO) YoloV4

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm working with YoloV4 model object detection. I'm trying to train the custom dataset but I'm constantly getting this error line:

```
Can't open label file. (This can be normal only if you use MSCOCO): data/obj/13_PNG.rf.c87d3ef90086ec0d21254a8a7c97147a.txt 
Can't open label file. (This can be normal only if you use MSCOCO): data/obj/13_PNG.rf.c87d3ef90086ec0d21254a8a7c97147a.txt 
Can't open label file. (This can be normal only if you use MSCOCO): data/obj/13_PNG.rf.c87d3ef90086ec0d21254a8a7c97147a.txt
```

Training file paths don't seem to match but I can't figure out how to fix that problem. I'm struggling for hours.

The command I'm trying to run the training process with:

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/custom-yolov4-detector.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show
```

And the train files and directories:

```
%cd /content/darknet/                                   
%cp {dataset.location}/train/_classes.txt data/obj.names                                    
%mkdir -p data/obj                                    
#copy image and labels                                    
%cp {dataset.location}/train/*.jpg data/obj/                                
%cp {dataset.location}/valid/*.jpg data/obj/ 
%cp {dataset.location}/train/*.txt data/obj/                                  
%cp {dataset.location}/valid/*.txt data/obj/                                  
                               
                                    
with open('data/obj.data', 'w') as out:                                   
  out.write('classes = 2\n')                                    
  out.write('train = data/train.txt\n')                                   
  out.write('valid = data/valid.txt\n')                                   
  out.write('names = data/obj.names\n')                                   
  out.write('backup = backup/')                                   
                                    
#write train file (just the image list)                                   
import os                                   
                                    
with open('data/train.txt', 'w') as out:                                    
  for img in [f for f in os.listdir(dataset.location + '/train') if f.endswith('jpg')]:                                   
    out.write('data/obj/' + img + '\n')                                   
                                    
#write the valid file (just the image list)                                   
import os                                   
                                    
with open('data/valid.txt', 'w') as out:                                    
  for img in [f for f in os.listdir(dataset.location + '/valid') if f.endswith('jpg')]:                                   
    out.write('data/obj/' + img + '\n')
```

Comment: Did you try to use absolute path in train/valid.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your labels(annotations) and the training image names are the same. If there is a difference between labels and image names, then it will cause this particular error. I had the same error when working with annotation files. For me, it happened when I had to convert from .png to .jpg and that changed the filename in the process.